# r - using iterators and iterpc packages; Can I create a subset of iterator?

Tags: r, foreach, iterator

I've created an iterator using iterpc, and then wrapped it by the iterators::iter package.

```
iter<-iterpc(nrow(data),4,ordered=TRUE,replace=TRUE)
it<-iter_wrapper(iter)
```

I then do a calculation using foreach

```
calcs<-foreach(i=it)%dopar%{
    blah}
```

My issue is that I do not want to use every element in the iterator. I want to randomly choose certain elements of the iterator, say 1000 of them. (computation time is an issue)
How do I choose a random subset of the iterator?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the permutation iterator works sequentially, so there's no way of randomly sampling. What you can do is write an iterator that calls `nextElem` repeatedly on a parent iterator to return a thinned version. This example creates a thinned version of an iterator via some "thin" parameter:

```
 > thinit = function(iterator,thin){
   iter(
        function(){
            for(i in 1:(thin-1)){
               nextElem(iterator)
            }
            nextElem(iterator)}
        )
   }
```

Note I call it `thin-1` times in the loop so that the last call is the iterator return value.

So, starting with a simple 1:100 iterator:

```
 > i1 <- iter(1:100)
```

Make a thinned version:

```
 > i10 = thinit(i1, 10)
```

Then the loop output is thinned:

```
 > foreach(i=i10) %dopar% {i}
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 20

[[3]]
[1] 30
```

etc. Now, you could make the wrapper call `nextElem` a random number of times (as long as it returns a `nextElem` call then it will work as an iterator) to get a random sample from your parent iterator. You wouldn't be able to get *exactly* 250 samples from the permutations, but if you know there are 2500 permutations and you call `nextElem` until `runif(1)>.9` you'll get 250 on average... Or something. Like this:

```
> pthin = function(iterator, p){
   iter(
     function(){
       while(runif(1)<p){
         nextElem(iterator)
         }
       nextElem(iterator)
      }
    )
   }
> i1 <- iter(1:100)
> ip10 = pthin(i1,.9)
> unlist(foreach(i=ip10) %dopar% {i})
 [1]  1  9 18 19 22 28 35 38 53 55 63 67 81 84 86 89 95 98
> i1 <- iter(1:100)
> ip10 = pthin(i1,.9)
> unlist(foreach(i=ip10) %dopar% {i})
 [1]  15  19  21  24  45  59  63  70  73  76  79  88  94 100
> i1 <- iter(1:100)
> ip10 = pthin(i1,.9)
> unlist(foreach(i=ip10) %dopar% {i})
[1] 10 50 62 76 79 81 97
```

Note that the parent iterator is called big-N times, but the sampling means the meat of your loop in `{i}` is only called the small number of times, which I suspect is where most of the time is spent.

If you really insist on a given N samples from the parent iterator, and you know the number of elements in the iterator, compute a sample of N from that and use an iterator wrapper as above that keeps calling `nextElem` on the parent until it gets to the next index in your sample, then returns that. It will have to keep the state of which samples to return in the closure, as in my examples. Can't quite get that working at the moment (more coffee needed) so here's an alternative approach:

Create an iterator wrapper that returns an iterator that produces the original iterator's values along with a consecutive index number from 1 to N. This is like the python `zip` function. Then only work on those iterations where the index number is in a subset. The length of the original iterator should be known to generate the subset. Example:

This is my `zip` iterator wrapper. It returns an iterator that generates list elements where `$index` is a consecutive index and `$value` are the values from the parent iterator:

```
> zipit = function(iz){
    itn=1
    iter(
       function(){
          itn<<-itn+1
          list(index=itn-1,value=nextElem(iz))
          }
        )
     }
```

Now create a permutation iterator as you want. We know this one has 10 elements in total, so generate a sample of 4 values from 10:

```
> I <- iterpc(5, 2)
> it <- iter_wrapper(I)
> subset = sample(10,4)
```

Now your main loop has a test and only processes (in this case a simple sum of the values) those iterations in the subset:

```
> foreach(i=zipit(it), .combine=c) %do% {if(i$index %in% subset)sum(i$value)}
[1] 4 7 8 9
```